# 200,000 images in single folder in linux, performance issue or not?

Tags: linux, performance, image, file-io, filesystems

I have a php/mysql website with over **200,000** images in single folder **(linux server)**.  I don't think, that I will never need to see them in file explorer, instead they will be viewed on website on their individual pages.  They are just displayed in product page on website.  **File system is ext3**. so is it wise to save them in single folder?  can it slow down the site's performance?

Comment: Which file system are you using?

Comment: ext3 is the file system, I hope

Comment: Remember to accept the suitable answer if one is given. This will let others know that the answer exists.

Comment: Why not use a database such as MySQL? And more disturbing is why didn't anyone mention that ?!?!

Comment: hi poni, database is the worst option to store images (if they are in large scale), I think

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ext3 uses tree to hold directory contents, so its capability to handle a large number of files in a single directory is better than that of those file systems with linear directory listings. 
Here you can read [the description of the tree](http://ext2.sourceforge.net/2005-ols/paper-html/node3.html) used to keep directory contents.

However, 200K files is still a huge number. It's reasonable to move them into subdirectories based on first n characters of file names. This approach lets you keep only file names and not directory names, and when you need to access the file, you know where (in which subdirectory) to look for it.

Comment: You can check if dir_index is enabled (and the hashing algorythm used) using dumpe2fs, and enable/disable dir_index and select hashing algorythm with tune2fs.

Comment: Is there a true benefit of moving the files to subdirectorys? There are still 200K files on the disk. The question is if accessing files through a 'visible' folder tree is better than trough the internal ext3 index tree.

Comment: @dronus it appears, that on some filesysems linear file list would be a bit faster than hierarchical one for certain operations. So the answer to your question depends on what you want to accomplish and on what file system. In other words - measure it.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to have been answered at the below link.

https://serverfault.com/questions/43133/filesystem-large-number-of-files-in-a-single-directory

Answer (score 2):

*I know an answer was chosen, I want to add a solution on improving the performance, for interest*

Querying the directory listing each time will cost the most overhead, if the directory listing returns all results every time.

You can improve performance by storing the listing in an indexed database (say SQLite) and just query the results from there. You can select a subset of records and implement pagination much easier this way, and filter the results too.

Comment: as I said, I will never need a requirement to list all files in directory listing.  Just need to display product-1.jpg or product-x.jpg on the webpage (x is any number).

Answer (score 0):

file systems determine performance, and 200,000 images without indexing will slow down performance in ext2 (or NTFS)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite probable that some time in the future you might want to do something where having all the images dumped in a single folder will hurt you, or something unexpected will happen and you will regret doing it that way.

On the other hand, having the files split into several folders doesn't seem to have many disadvantages, besides added complexity in dealing with them.

Performance will vary depending on your filesystem, its configuration and your access patterns. I believe it would be quite strange for performance to be perceptibly worse if splitting the files between multiple folders.

So I'd say, split into different folders...

Answer (score 0):

This paper over an ext2 variant for web scenarios might interest you: [hashFS: Applying Hashing to Optimize File Systems for Small File Reads](http://storageconference.org/2010/Papers/SNAPI/4.Lensing.pdf).

We have seen a better ext2 performance with a flat file set (more files in a directory) than a deep file set (deeper directory tree) for a web scenario (assumptions stated in paper).

Granted, in retrospect the evaluation should have been more extensive. But it might be worth reading.