# Does a large number of directories negatively impact performance?

Tags: file, directory, directory-structure

I'm intending to use files to store data as a kind of cache for PHP-generated files, so as to avoid having to re-generate them every time they are loaded (their contents only change once a day).

One thing I have noticed in the past is that if a directory has a large number of files inside, reaching the thousands, it will take a long time for an FTP program to load its contents, sometimes even crashing the computer that's trying to load them. So I'm looking into a tree-based system, where each file is stored in a subfolder based on its ID. So for example a file with the ID 123456 would be stored as `12/34/56.html`. In this way, each folder will have at most 100 items (except in the event that there are millions of files, but that is extremely unlikely to happen).

Is this a good idea, is it overkill, or is it unnecessary? The question essentially boils down to: "What is the best way to organise a large number of files?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The answer depends on

- OS (e.g. Linux vs Windows) and
- filesystem (e.g. ext3 vs NTFS).

2) Keep in mind that when you arbitrarily create a new subdirectory, you're using more inodes

3) Linux usually handles "many files/directory" better than Windows

4) A couple of additional links (assuming you're on Linux):

- [200,000 images in single folder in linux, performance issue or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003885/200-000-images-in-single-folder-in-linux-perfomance-issue-or-not)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/43133/filesystem-large-number-of-files-in-a-single-directory
- https://serverfault.com/questions/147731/do-large-folder-sizes-slow-down-io-performance
- http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html
  *

Comment: Well, I'm developing on a Windows machine but the site itself is running on Linux. I frequently back up the server's files to my computer, so whatever solution I go for would have to be multiplatform. I guess the main issue is the inodes, since I know absolutely nothing about those!